# NSMutableURLRequest forHTTPHeaderField key not properly set

Tags: swift, http-headers, urlsession

In my app, while making an API call I need to pass location in an header. But it's key is converted to CamelCase. Please find my code below

```
let session = URLSession.shared
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!)
request.httpMethod = "GET"

request.addValue("XYZLocation", forHTTPHeaderField: "location")

let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

    if (error == nil){
       let str = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
       print("Response : \(String(describing: str))")
    }
    else{
       print("Error : \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
    }
})
print("Header : \(String(describing: request.allHTTPHeaderFields))")
task.resume()
```

Log output is below

```
Header : Optional(["Location": "XYZLocation"])
```

How can I maintain the header key case sensitivity. Please help me.

Comment: First of all, use the native Swift equivalent, `URLRequest` instead of `NSMutableURLRequest`. Second of all, if you look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutableurlrequest/1407676-addvalue) of `addValue`, you can see that the header values are case insensitive to conform to HTTP RFC, so you should also be using case insensitive headers in your backend.

Comment: @DávidPásztor with `URLRequest` too it's same. Also we can't make changes to backend. Why is it with `Location` header only. It's working properly for other header keys.